# how to stop slave server in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for how to stop the slave server for some time.
But I want the server to be available for reads by the application but it is not supposed to replicate data from master.

Is there anyway here...?
shuting down is not I prefer here.

Regards,
UDAY

Answer (score 1):

We can stop the write activity on salve with fsycnLock() on the query prompt of mongodb.

[db.fsyncLock()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/)

It returns some thing like

```
    {
       "info" : "now locked against writes, use db.fsyncUnlock() to unlock",
        "seeAlso" : "http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/fsync+Command",
        "ok" : 1
    }
```

we can unlock using fsyncUnlock().

This is similar to STOP SLAVE in general RDBMS's.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the [slave delay](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Master+Slave#MasterSlave-%5Cslavedelay) option.  If you wanted to stop sync altogether, then that would be more problematic.  I assume you want your reads to stay fast for a certain amount of time while writes are completing on the master or something similar (rollback perhaps) but that you do want it to catch up eventually.

Comment: No Adam, what am i expecting is... I want to have the replication of data from master to slave to be stopped for a period of time. Like STOP SLAVE (which we have in MYSQL). After a period of time, I would like to revoke the slave activity using SATART SLAVE like thing.

Comment: hmmm, well if it is a replica set, you can restart the mongod instance without the --replset flag and on a different port, as described here: 

http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2011/02/22/resizing-your-oplog/

Instead of the mthod described you could make your slave "stale" on purpose by manipulating the oplog and then resync it later to catch up.  As far as I know though, there is no command or supported way to do this.  I'll have a think and see if I can figure out another way....